# jQuery UI Draggable: Correctly having the mouse follow sortable items when zooming items with CSS on dragStart

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I am attempting to allow sorting items that have a long height. The height of the objects may be more then the users screen, which will make it difficult to click and drag the items (and still have a general overview of *what* the items are.

I devised a simple plan to go and change the zoom level of the items when beginning the start of the drag, but this does not seem to correctly work.

**See the JSFiddle and try moving the blocks around to see the issue**: http://jsfiddle.net/sh4zx63w/7/

```
$('#container ul').sortable({
    revert: true,
    placeholder: "dropstyle",
    start: function (evt, ui) {
        pointerY = (evt.pageY - $('#container').offset().top) / zoom - parseInt($(evt.target).css('top'));
        pointerX = (evt.pageX - $('#container').offset().left) / zoom - parseInt($(evt.target).css('left'));
    },
    beforeStop: function (event, ui) {
        $('#container').css({
            zoom: 1,
            'overflow': 'none',
            'height': 'auto'
        })
    },
    drag: function (evt, ui) {
        var canvasTop = $('').offset().top;
        var canvasLeft = $('#container').offset().left;
        var canvasHeight = $('#container').height();
        var canvasWidth = $('#container').width();

        // Fix for zoom
        ui.position.top = Math.round((evt.pageY - canvasTop) / zoom - pointerY);
        ui.position.left = Math.round((evt.pageX - canvasLeft) / zoom - pointerX);

        // Check if element is outside canvas
        if (ui.position.left < 0) ui.position.left = 0;
        if (ui.position.left + $(this).width() > canvasWidth) ui.position.left = canvasWidth - $(this).width();
        if (ui.position.top < 0) ui.position.top = 0;
        if (ui.position.top + $(this).height() > canvasHeight) ui.position.top = canvasHeight - $(this).height();

        // Finally, make sure offset aligns with position
        ui.offset.top = Math.round(ui.position.top + canvasTop);
        ui.offset.left = Math.round(ui.position.left + canvasLeft);
    }
});
```

I have tried the click and dragging on Firefox, Chrome and Internet Explorer, and all of them are not working correctly.

In Chrome and Internet Explorer, dragging the brown box (the first box) is not possible, you need to move the smaller boxes up if you want to push the box down.

Firefox is better, but it still has problems, which can be seen when attempting to drag the brown box to the bottom. Dragging the smaller boxes appears to work much better.

Comment: It looks like this issue might actually be caused by jQuery not correctly counting the width & height of elements when using CSS transformations. http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11114